# Can I use bot framework to send/update message as a user in MS Teams?

Tags: .net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is it possible to use bot framework to send / update message as a user rather than the bot as the sender of message (perhaps after some form of authentication with the user that allows the bot to perform such operations)?

Below is an illustration of the current situation:
I have sent a message by person A into Teams channel, and I would like to do an update to the message using bot framework as Graph API does not support update of message. However, the message does not get updated although there was no error.

This is placed in a web api controller "/test". Hence the update will be trigger by sending a POST to /test.

```
ServiceClientCredentials service = new CustomLoginCredentials();

var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apac/"), service);
var newActivity = MessageFactory.Text($"hello: updated on {DateTime.Now}");


string destActivityId = "this is the activity id of the existing message sent using person A account on MS Teams";

string conversationId = $"channelidhere;messageid={destActivityId}";
connectorClient.Conversations.UpdateActivityAsync(conversationId, destActivityId, newActivity, default(CancellationToken));
```

CustomLoginCredentials

```
 public class CustomLoginCredentials:ServiceClientCredentials
    {
        private string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }
        public override void InitializeServiceClient<T>(ServiceClient<T> client)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CustomLoginCredentials:InitializeServiceClient 1");
            IPublicClientApplication publicClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create("clientid")
                  .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "tenantId")
                  .Build();

            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = publicClient.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }, "personA MS email", new NetworkCredential("", "personA MS email password").SecurePassword).ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            AuthenticationToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

        }

        public override async Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("request");

            if (AuthenticationToken == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Token Provider Cannot Be Null");

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthenticationToken);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            await base.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use on-behalf-attribute to send message as a user - Could you please check [User attribution for bots messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/respond-to-task-module-submit?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-1#user-attribution-for-bots-messages) is this what you are looking for?

Comment: are you still facing issue? Could you please update?

Comment: Thank you, @Nikitha-MSFT for the suggestion and apologies on the late reply, just got to test it out and it works. May I ask, is there any way I can later, update / delete that message being send out by the bot on behalf of the user (i.e. if bot send a message on behalf of Alice, how can I update / delete that message later on behalf of Alice)?

Comment: Please check updating messages to update the message send.try if that helps?

Comment: okay. Also can I check that, although it shows "Alice via bot", can Alice update/delete that bot message that was sent on behalf of her on MS Teams interface?

Comment: otherwise, will there be any other alternative to achieving: bot sending messages on behalf of the user and user can later modify/delete the message (on MS Teams)?

Comment: User cannot modify the message. you need to use bot to update the message. Please check [updating messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conversations#updating-messages)

Comment: I see. Got that, thank you @Nikitha-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where a bot sends messages on behalf of a user, attributing the message to that user helps with engagement and showcase a more natural interaction flow. This feature allows you to attribute a message from your bot to a user on whose behalf it was sent. You can use on-behalf-attribute to send message as a user -  please check [User attribution for bots messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/respond-to-task-module-submit?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-1#user-attribution-for-bots-messages)